# Receiver Peak Output Voltage

Tags: signal-power

I am currently on a university course doing a telecommunications module. I have been doing some past papers today and came across a question around peak output voltage of an optical receiver and have 0 clue how to do. I have attached the question for reference, not after the answer really, just more a walk through of how to tackle calculating peak output voltage for a receiver.

Thanks in advance!!!

[image: Question]

Edit:

Please see attached current working, is this along the right lines?

[image]

Comment: Hi Jamie. This question is probably a better fit for https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ which the stack exchange site for electrical engineering.

Answer (score 0):

Just some hints:
dBm stands for dBmW as in "milliwatts".
With the responsivity and the signal power, you can calculate a current through the load resistor, giving you an Input voltage for the amplifier.
To go from average power to peak power, think about how the signal looks.
User the capacity values, to assess the Overall frequency Response by looking at the complex voltage divider created by both capacities.

**EDIT**

Your attempt is not so bad. Just two things.

1. Think of the optical signal as a PWM ON/OFF kind of signal, where "1" and "0" are happening equally often. Then the peak power is average power +3dB, or, thinking in amplitudes, the induced peak current is higher by a factor of $\sqrt 2$, which gives you $0.8\mu A \cdot \sqrt 2=1.313\mu A$.
2. You are off by factor $10$ when calculating the voltage. Including the above mentioned $\sqrt 2$, the voltage at the resistor is $1.313\mu A \cdot 1000\Omega = 1.313mV$, which yields, with $26dB$ gain, a voltage of $22.574mV$ at the amplifier output.

Regarding the second question:

1. Your equivalent circuit is wrong. The amplifier resistance is parallel to the load resistance, as is its capacitance. For assessing this question, leave the amplifier itself out. Only the frequency response at the input considering the parasital capacitance matters.
2. You get a low pass circuit consisting of diode capacitance, load resistor and amplifier capacitance. Amplifier resistance can be ditched, as it is much larger, than load resistance and parallel to it. The diode itself is replaced by a current source. Your circuit then looks like this:
   [image]
3. What you see there is a lowpass filter. You might understand it better, if you replace the parallel resistor and current source by a series resistor and voltage source. However, you need to calculate the cutoff frequency of this lowpass filter.

$$f_c=\frac{1}{2\pi (C_d + C_a)R}$$

Plug in the values and it will yield $f_c \approx 144\text{MHz}$
Your signal's bitrate is $125\text{Mbit/s}$, which directly translates to a frequency of $125\text{MHz}$. So your signal will not be affected, which is why a post amplification equalisation is not neccessary.

Comment: What is a complex voltage divider? I am not from an electronics background at all so have 0 clue, the material in the slide decks on this topic isn't great either. Also, thanks for your initial help!

Comment: See my edit for solution and explanation.